# MariaDB: Split a semicolon separated string and calculate mean value

Tags: split, mariadb, mean

I have a column in my MariaDB table that contains an undefined amount of semicolon separated integer values as a string (e.g. "123;456;789;123").

Inside of the INSERT-Trigger of this table I want to calculate the mean value of the integers in the string.

Any ideas on how to do this string split and mean calculation in a short and easy way?

Comment: That is a database anti pattern....you should look for a better way to store your data in order to avoid bigger problems in the future.

Comment: It is possible in a lengthy, ugly, Stored Routine.  My brain hurts at thinking about how to write such.

Comment: @Hackerman, I know, but that was not the question ;)

Comment: Good luck when this blows over ;)